# ASP .Net MVC 3 HTTPContext Wrapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In an effort to move to TDD and unit testable code I have read that I should be using an HttpContext wrapper. In my service layer as well as in my controllers I have to access the HttpContext Session for some data I have stored there.

Can someone provide an example of an HttpContext Wrapper implementation for MVC 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MVC Runtime already provides a [HttpContextWrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextwrapper.aspx). What you need to implement is a wrapper around Session state, and encapsulate the fact that state is being accessed through `HttpContext` so that you can use DI or a Mocking framework to create a non-`HttpContext` backed SessionWrapper for your tests. [Brad Wilson provides some good information on how to do this](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2011/02/advanced-aspnet-mvc-3-presentation.html). However, if you don't want to wade through the video (which contains advanced topics) here is the gist for wrapping Session:

**Create an interface representing strongly typed object you could typically access through Session:**

```
public interface ISessionWrapper
{
    public UserPreferences CurrentUserPreferences{get;set;}
    ...
}
```

**Create an implementation of the interface that uses Session as a backing store:**

```
public class HttpContextSessionWrapper : ISessionWrapper
{
    private T GetFromSession<T>(string key)
    {
        return (T) HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
    }

    private void SetInSession(string key, object value)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
    }

    public UserPreferences CurrentUserPreferences
    {
        get { return GetFromSession<UserPreferences>("CurrentUserPreferences"); }
        set { SetInSession("CurrentUserPreferences", value); }
    }

    ...
}
```

Resolve the instance in your `Controller` using `DependencyResolver` (or preferably this is done through you DI  framework of choice). Assuming you are using the SessionWrapper in a majority of Controllers, this could be done in a common `BaseController`:

```
var SessionWrapper = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISessionWrapper>();
```