# Cookie wrapper in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, wrapper, dry, httpcontext

I am trying to create a cookie wrapper, so that i can use it to set and get cookie values in my actions in mvc.
We already have HttpContextWrapper which has Request and Response properties.

HttpContextWrapper:

```
 public class HttpContextWrapper : IHttpContext
    {
        private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;
        private readonly HttpContextBase _httpContextBase;

        public HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            _httpContext = httpContext;
            _httpContextBase = new System.Web.HttpContextWrapper(httpContext);
        }

        public HttpRequest Request
        {
            get { return _httpContext.Request; }
        }

        public HttpContextBase Base
        {
            get { return _httpContextBase; }
        }

        public HttpResponse Response
        {
            get { return _httpContext.Response; }
        }

    }
```

IHttpContext:

```
public interface IHttpContext
    {
        HttpRequest Request { get; }
        HttpContextBase Base { get; }
        HttpResponse Response { get; }
    }
```

1) How can i reuse this wrapper to set and get cookie values?

2) The purpose of warpping cookie values is to able to perform unit testing. I am setting and getting the cookie values directly in my action methods. Instead i want to make it reusable, and unit testable.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks

WH

Comment: Although the following post is addressing a wrapper for Session the approach presented may be helpful for deciding how to handle your requirement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940033/asp-net-mvc-3-httpcontext-wrapper

Comment: This may also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767131/difference-between-httpcontext-and-httpcontextwrapper-in-terms-of-unit-testing-a

Comment: Thanks @DavidTansey for responding. I have the idea of session warpper since i am already using it . I am looking for something related to cookies( Response.Cookies)

Comment: @DavidTansey- The link provided uses -  NSubstitute, but i am using Moq. I still think wrapper makes much easier to unit test. Not sure if this is achievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidTansey for the inputs.

Implemented the following code and able to mock Response.Cookies. However this is not context wrapper which i was expecting, but at least i am able to move forward with this.

Unit Test files:

public class HttpContextMock : HttpContextBase
    {
        private HttpResponseBase response;

```
    public override HttpResponseBase Response
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.response == null)
            {
                this.response = new HttpResponseMock();
            }
            return this.response;
        }
    }
}

public class HttpResponseMock : HttpResponseBase
{
    private HttpCookieCollection cookies;

    public override HttpCookieCollection Cookies
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.cookies == null)
            {
                this.cookies = new HttpCookieCollection();
            }

            return this.cookies;
        }
    }
}
```

Test.cs:

```
public void TestMethod()
     {

 var _controller = new HomeContoller();
 var httpContext = new HttpContextMock();
 _controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContext, new RouteData(),_controller);

  var result = _controller.Welcome(userId);

  Assert.AreEqual("Welcome",  _controller.Response.Cookies["TitleMessage"].Value);

}
```

HomeController:

```
public jsonresult Welcome(int userid)
    {

 ....................

  var cookie = new HttpCookie("TitleMessage") {Value = "Welcome"};
  Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

}
```